# Parallel conversion of signal through a low res & fast ADC and high res & slow ADC

Tags: sensor, adc

Would there be any benefit to splitting analogue sensor signals and sending them in parallel through a low res & high throughput rate ADC and high res & low throughput rate ADC, and analysing/comparing the separate data/sticking it together? Any systems this is used in? Maybe the signal would be somewhere imbetween the ADC specs (ie. bandwidth is double/equal the throughput rate and SQNR is high/low)

(

Previously I have used very standard sensor set ups with Arduino Mega etc. This week I have been venturing into EE territory to improve the bit between 'resistance information' and network training. WOW, analog electronics is complicated, hats off to you guys in the know! I mostly work in physics/mathematical modeling of complex systems, so some basic theory is there, however really I have only been doing any EE for 5 days now.

@Wesley Lee The application is using neural networks to predict the various strains from sets of resistance measurements of a stretchy sensor array to predict its position/state. 
If it is then I might set something up and see if any significant increase in information (obviously there will be more data points) arises from it. If nobody does this anywhere, that would suggest it isn't worth it.

Comment: Are you asking this hypothetically or do you actually have an issue in mind?

Comment: the benefits of added complexity can be combined in one solution defined by better specifications for sensor bandwidth, SNR, stability, averaging, alarm thresholds ..etc. 1st define functions, resolution, accuracy, SNR, interference and outputs with signal rate and averaging , limits, tolerances for all inputs, temp range before you even think of design!!

Comment: Fast and slow are really bad quantifiers! What is the bandwidth of the signal and what are the sampling rates of the two ADCs? Also what is the desired resolution and the bit rate of the ADCs? Only then we can have a conversation.

Comment: @Tony Stewart Yes, I like your definition, and see your point. I have expanded a little, any areas you know that do this?

Comment: @vini_i

They certainly are! They are merely relative terms, I'm not really looking for a numerical breakdown of anything.

Comment: hey @benhorseradish  if you can define , I can design it.  accuracy, resolution, signal bandwidth, noise bandwidth, latency vs resolution requirement, the trick is communicating expectations for functions needed and environment to  or at least point form then convert to a spec like a datasheet for the clear requirements to be followed then by an optimal design by a skilled designer in th least cost, best performance. Otherwise it becomes an iteration of failure fixes

Comment: Tony, if I saw somewhere that a parallel pair of quite contrasting ADCs are converting the same signal, then I would definitely come back to you on such a thing, if you could help. I have designed what I think is a pretty well optimised design for a system, I am now waiting on delivery of parts. For much of it I have matched datasheets, after painstakingly learning the terminology, it has been quite a journey!

Comment: This question might mean I make a different system to have a play with together, or not, but that is another massive effort for me.

Comment: Without quantifying even relative is meaningless. Your one ADC could be 3 orders of magnitude slower than the bandwidth of your signal and have 24 bit resolution. The other ADC could be 3 orders of magnitude faster than your signal and have 2 bit resolution. They match your description relatively but both are worthless. Now that you have added more info a more engineering based conversation is possible.

Comment: @vini_i Resources such as these forums are incredibly valuable, and one of the most damaging things to them is very inexperienced students who insist on trying to portray themselves as experienced/knowledgeable.  STOP TALKING LIKE YOU ARE A SAGE.  You are not one. Only 4 months ago you asked whether SMT resistors have voltage ratings among other perfectly acceptable questions for a beginner to ask, because that is what you are.

Comment: @vini_i You have nothing useful to say because the question requires wisdom, not rote calculations. Please, continue to regurgitate your classnotes in answers, but how about saying 'I think' or 'according to this book', because you don't know.

Comment: I hope that while you might be angry at this response, you might consider it. My work is very interdisciplinary, I am often a beginner again and am quite used to dealing with people determined to try to be superior to everyone, but a lot of youngsters just starting out get very shut down by such things. Just be nice.

Comment: All i'm trying to do is get you to ask a better question. There a beginners here all the time and getting enough information to give a proper answer is a must. I was not the only one asking you for this information and you did eventually edit you question to include the information, but somehow i'm the bad guy. I also never typed in all caps which is usually just plain rude.

Comment: High speed / low speed fast/slow, relative terms are used all the time in high end literature, and everybody knows full well what it means. Manufacturers have ranges of ADCs called high speed, the book I answered with has it in the title, lol. The extra stuff I wrote essentially doesn't give any more information, apart from a bit of application. It was in the hope that it would bypass the pedantry which is sometimes necessary, but clearly not, the pedantry was all you were interested in stating.

Comment: All you then produced was a silly example of when things are double or half, and all this nonsense about whether or not a conversation is even possible, 'only then we can have a conversation', like you are some overarching authority, it's ridiculous. The question is not asking for a solution, it is asking for information. Quantity is simply not necessary.

Comment: I have been having meetings with EE researchers since, and people are perfectly capable. If you are incapable of talking about your field without just calculating something for someone, that's fine, but don't suggest that it is not possible for anything else to happen. How do you think you were taught?

Comment: In general terms, an ADC of N bits is equivalent to one of M bits if the sample rate is adjusted by (N-M) squared. So you can get the equivalent of (say) 3 bits more resolution if you run it at 9 times the speed. An 8 bit ADC is the same as a 16 bit ADC if it's running at 256 times the speed. And so on.

Answer (score 2):

GREAT, I have found a very recent book on this, if you are interested. It is called dual path parallel sampling / parallel sampling :

Power-Efficient High-Speed Parallel-Sampling ADCs for Broadband Multi-carrier Systems (Analog Circuits and Signal Processing)

'The authors focus on exploiting the a-priori knowledge of the system/application to develop enhancement techniques for ADCs, with particular emphasis on improving the power efficiency of high-speed and high-resolution ADCs for broadband multi-carrier systems.'

Implementations of the merits of parallel pipelined low res and SAR high res are discussed. Particularly good for increasing the dynamic range.

Answer (score 2):

Analog sensor signals are often considered slow changing (strain gauges, photoresistors). A typical digital sampling rate for industrial-scale systems, that do logging on sensors is 1 Hz. 
A good audio ADC will have 20 bits of effective dynamic range. This is huge, requiring better than 120dB SNR from the rest of the system if you're gonna do bit accurate measurements per sample.
Delta-Sigma converters can convert with 48kHz and up to somewhere around 2-300kHz.

Personally, I recommend going the route of an audio ADC if you need REALLY high dynamic range. 
For practicality IMO a 14-bit ADC (you can get these even faster) will do the job. Average some samples and you have a nice value with a low sigma. 
If the sensors are connected in a Wheatstone bridge, I recommend linearizing the bridge with a constant current drive, to increase the linear range of measurement.

My bottom line is, I cannot see a reasonable reason to do double ADC-ing, except for increasing both cost and complexity. Modern ADCs are so broad and cover so many niches, you should be able to find one that does everything with the needed speed and resolution.

For getting a good sensor value, maybe look into kalman filters, they do an excellent job if you give them enough variables, and they are super fast. (for a kalman filter, speed is more important than resolution, though both help)

And since you're working with a sensor array, you probably would like to use multi-channel ADCs.

I hope your project is going / went well.

( I know it's a late answer, but maybe someone else can benefit from it as well )